# How to validate incoming Urls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to validate incoming urls from my application following is the scenario

on url http://abc.com/login.aspx - need to validate incoming urls from anyone of following

http://xyz.com/start.aspx
http://xyz.net/start.aspx
http:/yyy.com
http://mydomain.com/gotologin.aspx

Now from http://abc.com/login.aspx - I have to check whether the user came from above any three link or not?

If use came from any of these link display the a custom message with the url.

Any help on this will be most appreciated.

I finished it with config file like
    http://xyz.com/start.aspx" value="6"/> 
Here is a need of assign a particular value to a user came from specific url so, I took the key of url. All is working fine on local system. But when I published the sites on production it is not working. The code and rest logics are fine.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to look at the "Referer" header on the request.

Comment: Specifically: Request.UrlReferrer.

Comment: +1 noting that it can be spoofed so cannot be relied upon as a security mechanism

Comment: Bob and others - Thanks for your support. I set the same and its working fine on my local machine with localhost:port// but while I deployed to production it is not working.

I made a test application only with one page.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
{
    case "http://xyz.com/start.aspx":
        // Do something
        break;
    case "http://xyz.net/start.aspx":
        // Do something else
        break;

    default: break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but we cant hard-code values in application. Can we get them from web.config? something like <add <key"http://xyz.com/start.aspx" value="6"/>

Comment: we want to avoid database interaction for this

Comment: OK, then yeah, just add the key/values to the appSettings section of your web.config like so: <add key="1" value="http://xyz.com/start.aspx" /> ... from the code you can access the values like so:  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["1"]

Comment: Thanks, I finished it with config file like 
<add key"http://xyz.com/start.aspx" value="6"/>
Here is a need of assign a particular value to a user came from specific url so, I took the key of url.

All is working fine on local system. But when I published the sites on production it is not working. The code and rest logics are fine. Any idea?